# Rudin Question Help

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

Given a set $A$ that has an upper bound,may we define $\sup A$ as $$\sup A = \max_{w \in A} \{\lim_{ \epsilon \to 0} w + \epsilon  \}$$ Is this equivalent?

**Problem**
(7) Fix $b>1$, $y>0$ and prove there is a unique real $x$ such that $b^x = y$ by completing the following outline: 
(a) For any positive integer $n$, $b^n -1 \geq n(b-1)$
(b) Hence $b-1 \geq n(b^{\frac{1}{n}} -1)$ 
(c) If $t>1$  and $n>(b-1)/(t-1)$ then $b^{\frac{1}{n}} < t$ 
(d) If $w$ is such that $b^w < y$ then $b^{w+\frac{1}{n}} <y$ for sufficiently large $n$; to see this, apply part (c) with $t = yb^{-w}$ 
(e) If $b^w > y$, then $b^{w-\frac{1}{n}} >y$ for sufficiently large $n$.
(f) Let $A$ be the set of all $w$ such that $b^w < y$, and show that $x = \sup A$ satisfies $b^x =y$
(g) Prove this $x$ is unique.

(a) We shall proceed by induction. For $n=1$, this is trivial, since $b^1-1 = 1(b-1)$. Suppose this is true for $n=k$, we need show that this holds for $n=k+1$. 
We wish to show that  $b^{k+1} -1 \geq (k+1)(b-1)$. We have that

\begin{eqnarray*}
b^{k+1} -1 &=& 
 b(b^k-1)+(b-1) \ &\geq& 
bk(b-1) + b-1 \ &=& 
b(k+1)(b-1) \ &\geq& 
(k+1)(b-1)

\end{eqnarray*}

(b) If we let $n=\frac{1}{k}$, then $b^{\frac{1}{k}} -1 \geq \frac{1}{k} (b-1)$, which implies $k(b^{\frac{1}{k}} -1) \leq b-1$.
(c) We have that $n > \frac{b-1}{t-1}$, so using (b),

\begin{eqnarray*}
(b-1) &\geq& 
 n(b^{\frac{1}{n}} - 1) \\ &\geq& 
 \frac{b-1}{t-1} (b^{\frac{1}{n}} - 1)\\
\end{eqnarray*}

Ergo,

$1 \geq 
  \frac{1}{t-1} (b^{\frac{1}{n}} - 1)$, which implies $t > b^{\frac{1}{n}}$, as desired.

```
(d) This is obvious if $t = yb^{-w}$, as we have, by (c), $yb^{-w} > b^{\frac{1}{n}}$ which implies $y > b^{w + \frac{1}{n}$. Now take $\lim_{n \to \infty} b^{w + \frac{1}{n}} = b^w <y$.   
 (e) Let $t= \frac{b^w}{y}$, and, by (c), $ \frac{b^w}{y} > b^{\frac{1}{n}}$, rearranging terms implies $y < b^{w -\frac{1}{n}}$. Obviously, for sufficiently large $n$, this holds true.   
 (f) By (d) and (e), we have that $$ b^{w+ \epsilon} < y < b^{w-\epsilon}$$ for $\epsilon>0$ Thus, $$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} b^{w+\epsilon} < y < \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} b^{w-\epsilon}$$ therefore there exists $x$ such that $b^x = y$. To show that $\sup A$ satisfies this, where $A := \{ w : b^w < y \}$, we note that $$\sup A = \max_{w \in A} \{\lim_{ \epsilon \to 0} w + \epsilon  \}$$. So, $x = \sup A$ satisfies $b^x = y$.   
 (g) Suppose that $x$ was not unique. Then we would have $b^x = b^z = y$ for $x \neq z$. Then $b^{x-z} = 1$. Since $b>1$, this may only occur if $x=z$, a contradiction. Thus $x$ is unique.
```

Why is it formatting in a tex environment? could someone fix this?

Comment: A=(0,1) has also an upper bound, but you mean something else, don't you? Perhaps you should rephrase the upper bound and be more precise

Comment: @Stefanos Well let's assume $\sup A$ exists. Is it equivalent to write it as I have?

Comment: No, you need to assume that max A exists, and that is different. Take A=(0,1). The RHS of what you have is not defined.

Answer (score 1):

The RHS is simply $$\max_{w\in A}\{\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}w+\epsilon\}=\max_{w\in A}\{w+\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\epsilon\}=\max_{w\in A}\{w+0\}=\max_{w\in A}\{w\}$$ so, no it is not equivalent, except $\max_{w \in A}$ exists.

Comment: then how may I write a $\sup$ in terms of \epsilon? I'm doing a problem from Rudin, I'll post it above, and you may see why I need a sort of def.

Comment: @AnthonyPeter  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infimum_and_supremum#Formal_definition